# CSS Transitions: Div does not move back to its original place

Tags: css

In my style.css I have this code:

```
.box {
    transform-origin: left top;
}
.to-right {
    transform: translate(200px, 0px);
}

.to-left{
    transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

When a button is clicked, the div with the box class moves to the right, as it should. When another button is clicked, then it should go back to its original place.

As you can see in my code, the value for moving right and later back is the same (200px). However, instead of moving back to the same space, it moves further away.

I thought, the problem may be that there is no origin and I added one to the box class. But the problem remains.

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

Here is my code:

style.css

```
.box {
    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;
}
.to-right {
    transform: translate(200px, 0px);
}

.to-left{
    transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
    background-color: yellow;
}

.move {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

The code for the div looks like this:

```
 <div class="box move" ng-class="{'box': boxClass == 1, 'to-right': boxClass == 2, 'to-left': boxClass == 3} ">
```

Maybe noteworthy, the div is placed within a bootstrap and angularjs application.

Comment: Please make a sniper and give all code which you was trying .

Comment: On the other one, change to `translate(0,0)`

Comment: @pol This works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Click the button, The box moves to right
 `{ transform: translate(200px, 0px); }`
and when click again, it should be moved first place . 
`{ transform: translate(0px, 0px); }`

```
.to-right {
  transform: translate(200px, 0px);
}

.to-left{
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```